# How to navigate tooltips popup by clicking custom buttons outside Chart.js v2 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, chart.js, chart.js2

Discussion on mobile usability under Chart.js v2 library,

Can we simulate click event on those "score points" in the RadarChart?
I'm asking this because, 
Desktop view and tablet view looks quite okay for "score points" navigation by clicking on those points within Chart to trigger external interactivity by returned index.

an popular example can be find is

```
$('#ChartV2').click(function(e) {
            var activePoints = myRadarChart.getElementsAtEvent(e);                  
            var firstPoint = activePoints[0];
            console.log(firstPoint);
            if (firstPoint !== undefined){
               alert(firstPoint._index); 
               //so then we can use 
              // index to hide show results in the  html elements out of canvas , etc
            }
```

});

But if you look into mobile view, 
under responsive:true, the chart will be much smaller by auto resizing, 
thus the points inside radarchart can be very small for mobile click,
same with labels, everything will be smaller and harder to click on.

Could it be customizable to let user navigate those "score points" 
(initially triggered by click on canvas manually )

can it be indirectly trigger by
external "prev", "next" navigation buttons 
on left and right side of the Radarchart
such as those slider /  carousel navigation buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by utilizing the chart instance methods

---

**Script**

```
var myRadarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    ...

(function (chart) {
    var helpers = Chart.helpers;

    var currentDatasetIndex;
    var currentPointIndex;

    $('#ChartV2').click(function (e) {
        // try getting an element close to the click
        var activePoints = chart.getElementAtEvent(e);
        var firstPoint = activePoints[0];

        if (firstPoint === undefined) {
            // otherwise pick the first visible element
            helpers.each(chart.data.datasets, function (dataset, datasetIndex) {
                if (firstPoint === undefined && this.isDatasetVisible(datasetIndex)) {
                    var meta = this.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex);
                    firstPoint = meta.data[0];
                }
            }, chart);
        }

        // need this check as we may have 0 visible elements
        if (firstPoint !== undefined) {
            currentDatasetIndex = firstPoint._datasetIndex;
            currentPointIndex = firstPoint._index;
            $('#prev, #next').removeAttr('disabled');
            updateView();
        }
    });

    $('#prev').click(function () {
        // we add (n - 1) and do a modulo n to move one step back in an n element array.
        if (currentPointIndex === 0)
            currentDatasetIndex = (currentDatasetIndex + chart.data.datasets.length - 1) % chart.data.datasets.length;
        currentPointIndex = (currentPointIndex + chart.data.labels.length - 1) % chart.data.labels.length;
        updateView();
    });

    $('#next').click(function () {
        currentPointIndex = (currentPointIndex + 1) % chart.data.labels.length;
        if (currentPointIndex === 0)
            currentDatasetIndex = (currentDatasetIndex + 1) % chart.data.datasets.length;
        updateView();
    });


    // this (hoisted) function will update the text and show the tooltip
    function updateView() {
        $('#value').text(
            chart.data.datasets[currentDatasetIndex].label + ' : ' +
            chart.data.labels[currentPointIndex] + ' : ' +
            chart.data.datasets[currentDatasetIndex].data[currentPointIndex]);

        // we mess around with an internal variable here - this may not work with a new version
        chart.tooltip._active = [ chart.getDatasetMeta(currentDatasetIndex).data[currentPointIndex] ];
        chart.tooltip.update();
        chart.render();
    }

}(myRadarChart));
```

If you want this functionality only for small screens, just add a screen size check to the above chart click handler and hide the buttons and label using media queries.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uxqL6rwf/